# Is there a way to put an anchor inside the title of an anchor when using fancy box lightbox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, title, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox Lightbox and when the fancybox opens displaying image the title of the image shows at the bottom of the image. This title is from the text put into the title attribute of the anchor tag that opens the lightbox. I need to put an anchor in this title attribute to link to another site. Is this possible? jQuery perhaps?

Thanks for your time.

Angela

Comment: Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/cWNw9/ for fancybox v2.x

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have applied it to the first image of div=col4 on this page, which appears as the 1st column, 1st image. [link](http://kimcolemanprojects.com/lighting_video.html). If you could have a look for me I just can't seem to get it to work. I put the Script in the head of the document. thanks so much. angela

Comment: Its now on this page http://kimcolemanprojects.com/suntrap.html It is applied to the first img in the col2 div. thanks for any advice

Comment: I saw your site and you certainly used the script, however on the same page you also have this `$(".fancybox").fancybox();` which overrides the first with the callback to get the `title`. Try removing it and just let the one with the `beforeLoad` callback.

Comment: thanks, that was the problem. :)